# FTP client in WPF C# won't open folders with accented characters

Tags: c#, ftp, client, character

One day, FileZilla decided not to let me download. (Right click, "Download" is gray), so I downloaded SmartFTP, but I didn't really like that.

So I asked myself, why not make one? So, I already have it half-working (can connect to ftp-servers, download, upload, moving in and out folders, and create directories), however, it can't open folders with accented and/or special characters in them (á, é, ö, #, etc.), and they also appear in the listbox like this: "Adatb?ziskezel?s", while the inbuilt stuff in windows shows it like this: "Adatbáziskezelés".

What could I do in order to make it work?

```
public string[] OpenFolder(string foldername)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(foldername);
            foldername = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            string[] downloadFiles;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
            try
            {
                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(
                          "ftp://" + IP + "/"+foldername+"/"));
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username,
                                                           password);
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                WebResponse response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response
                                                .GetResponseStream());

                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    result.Append(line);
                    result.Append("\n");
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
                result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
                reader.Close();
                response.Close();
                return result.ToString().Split('\n');
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                downloadFiles = null;
                return downloadFiles;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please post some code regarding the "opening file" action?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (line.Contains("#"))
{ 
     line = line.Replace("#", Uri.HexEscape('#'));
}
```

and so forth...